# Why in migration error calling seeder method?

Tags: laravel-5, migration

In my laravel 5.7 app in console I created new table migration script and seeder :

```
php artisan make:migration create_page_content_images_table --create="page_content_images"

php artisan make:seeder PageContentImagesWithInitData
```

Both files were created ok and I filled them database/migrations/2018_12_04_120422_create_page_content_images_table.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePageContentImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('page_content_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('page_content_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('page_content_id')->references('id')->on('page_contents')->onDelete('RESTRICT');

            $table->string('filename', 255);
            $table->boolean('is_main')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('is_video')->default(false);

            $table->string('video_type', 10)->nullable();
            $table->string('video_ext',  5)->nullable();

            $table->smallInteger('video_width')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('video_height')->nullable();

            $table->string('info', 255)->nullable();

            $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

            $table->unique(['page_content_id', 'filename'], 'page_contents_page_content_id_filename_unique');
            $table->index(['page_content_id', 'is_main'], 'page_contents_page_content_id_is_main');
            $table->index(['page_content_id', 'is_video', 'filename'], 'page_contents_page_content_id_is_video_filename');
            $table->index(['created_at'], 'page_content_message_documents_created_at_index');

        });
        Artisan::call('db:seed', array('--class' => 'PageContentImagesWithInitData'));   //database/seeds/PageContentImagesWithInitData.php
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('page_content_images');
    }
}
```

and database/seeds/PageContentImagesWithInitData.php :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class PageContentImagesWithInitData extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {


        DB::table('page_content_images')->insert([
            'id'                    => 1,
            'page_content_id'       => 1, // About
            'filename'              => 'your_vote.jpg',
            'is_main'               => false,
            'is_video'              => false,
            'video_type'            => null,
            'video_ext'             => null,
            'video_width'           => null,
            'video_height'          => null,
            'info'                  => 'Site slogan image',
        ]);

        DB::table('page_content_images')->insert([
            'id'                    => 2,
            'page_content_id'       => 1, // About
            'filename'              => 'our_boss.jpg',
            'is_main'               => false,
            'is_video'              => false,
            'video_type'            => null,
            'video_ext'             => null,
            'video_width'           => null,
            'video_height'          => null,
            'info'                  => 'Our boss photo',
        ]);

        DB::table('page_content_images')->insert([
            'id'                    => 3,
            'page_content_id'       => 1, // About
            'filename'              => 'our_main_manager.jpg',
            'is_main'               => false,
            'is_video'              => false,
            'video_type'            => null,
            'video_ext'             => null,
            'video_width'           => null,
            'video_height'          => null,
            'info'                  => 'Our main manager',
        ]);

        DB::table('page_content_images')->insert([
            'id'                    => 4,
            'page_content_id'       => 2, // Contact Us
            'filename'              => 'office_building.jpeg',
            'is_main'               => true,
            'is_video'              => false,
            'video_type'            => null,
            'video_ext'             => null,
            'video_width'           => null,
            'video_height'          => null,
            'info'                  => 'Office building',
        ]);

        DB::table('page_content_images')->insert([
            'id'                    => 5,
            'page_content_id'       => 2, // Contact Us
            'filename'              => 'office.jpeg',
            'is_main'               => true,
            'is_video'              => false,
            'video_type'            => null,
            'video_ext'             => null,
            'video_width'           => null,
            'video_height'          => null,
            'info'                  => 'Our Office',
        ]);

    }
}
```

The problem is that running migration command I got error:

```
 ReflectionException  : Class PageContentImagesWithInitData does not exist
  at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779
```

I checked and do not see any misspelling or case issue... 
I run in console next commands :

```
php artisan config:cache
composer dump-autoload
```

But I got error anyway...

Why error and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried removing the `Artisan::call` from within the migration file and running the seeder separately?

Comment: Yes, I tried. The same error.

Comment: could it be a namespace issue?

Comment: But I created these migration/seeder files with console commands(I show them). I did not modify header of these files manually..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and I failed to find valid decision, after some search I found 
these 2 files

```
/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php
/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php
```

which included my prior seeder classes, but not current I failed to run
I manually removed vendor directory and run

```
composer install
```

and cleared cache

That helped!
You can try this way!

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is with your seeder namespaces, 
you can use --path instead of --class, Try this kind of thing,

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', array('--path' => 'path/to/my/seed'));
```

Comment: I modified migration script:

        Artisan::call('db:seed', array('--path' => 'database/seeds/PageContentImagesWithInitData'));

and got error :
  The "--path" option does not exist.  
I searched like here 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations
and looks it has --path options, but it not (always) works.